# Error trying to parse hashmap getValue() as int

Tags: java, hashmap, raw-types

I have a hashmap of words, and the frequency
I want to use the frequency as an integer

```
     for (Map.Entry me : hm.entrySet()) {
        int freq = me.getValue();
        //do something with int
     }
```

This keeps getting different errors:
`Cannot convert from Object to int`, `The method parseInt(boolean) in the type PApplet is not applicable for the arguments (object)`

How do I workaround this?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet?

Comment: מה קורה תום ? פונה אלייך בשפה שלנו. החברה בסטאק אוברפלו מאוד קשוחים. אם אתה מפרסם שאלה יכנסו בך חזק אם לא תקפיד על ניסוח תקין לשאלות שלך. בינתיים רק אני הצבעתי עבור השאלה שלך, אני חושב שהיא לגיטימית אבל יש פה הרבה שיתעצבנו על שאלה כזו. עשה טובה - פרסם עוד מהקוד שלך כדי שנבין מאיפה בדיוק מגיעה השגיאה שלך. שמור על עצמך סחבי, יש לך גב פה :)

Answer (score 3):

You should [avoid using raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), if you are using jdk7+, try create map this way:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> me : hm.entrySet()) {
     int freq = me.getValue();
     //do something with int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this an Anti-Answer, but this does have its uses in a pinch.
The answer by [user6690200](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6690200/user6690200) is correct IMHO.

But what can you do if you can not control the creation of the Map, and are given an instance of the raw map ?

In this case, the quickest solution would be casting and surrounding the problematic casting with proper exception try-catch net:

```
for (Map.Entry me : hm.entrySet()) {
    try {
       int freq = (Integer)me.getValue();
       //do something with int
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
       // handle exception resposibly!
    }
 }
```